# .Net regular expression to remove all text that captures value of a json string

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to use a regular expression in a .Net application that removes all characters except the value of the key i specify in the regex

Here is the text string:

```
{"fontFamily":"Arial","fontSize":9.000000E+000,"fontStretch":null,"fontStyle":null,"fontWeight":null,"textDecoration":null,"fontColor":"#FF000000","textAlignment":"TopLeft","textAutoSize":false,"textSizeBehavior":"Fixed"}
```

Ideally, i'm hoping to have something that can be used to capture all these values, when i specify which key i need that would be stored into separate variables.

For instance, I want to use the regex to match the value of the fontFamily. The returned string would just be Arial

Comment: Do you have access to C#/VB.NET code? What is the app?

Comment: It looks like your data is in JSON format. Could you parse it instead of trying to use a regular expression?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using an application that has much beyond using regex. So very limited in doing anything other than accomplish this with regex

Comment: I believe _values can contain nested objects as well. `{"abc":{"xyz":123}}` is that something to consider and plan for ?

Comment: The json strings i'm working with has no nested objects

Comment: If you put in data dynamically, you can construct a regex at runtime. Example `"\""` + fontFamily + `"\":([^,{}]*)"` then after a match, trim the contents of group 1 of any unnecessary quotes  if necessary. Or, use `"\""` + fontFamily + `"\":\"?([^,{}"]*)"` which needs no trim.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it in C#

```
string target =
    @"
      {""fontFamily"":""Arial"",""fontSize"":9.000000E+000,""fontStretch"":null,""fontStyle"":null,""fontWeight"":null,""textDecoration"":null,""fontColor"":""#FF000000"",""textAlignment"":""TopLeft"",""textAutoSize"":false,""textSizeBehavior"":""Fixed""}
    ";

string myinput = "fontFamily";
Console.WriteLine("Searching: {0}", myinput);

Regex rx = new Regex( "\"" + myinput + "\":\"?([^,{}\"]*)" );

Match m = rx.Match( target );
while ( m.Success )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", m.Groups[1].Value);
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Output

```
Searching: fontFamily
Found: Arial
```

Comment: Thanks @sln, i am unable to place the string dynamically, but I could break it up and run the string through again to chop off the remaining characters. Would that be possible? Hope I'm making sense....

Comment: @DanSchmidt - `i am unable to place the string dynamically` -  Why is that? In my code sample I show you how to do it, see **_myinput_**.